# SQL query to count the number of untested versions after the last tested version

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database that looks like this :

```
Component         Version         tested
----------------------------------------
A                 1.00.00         yes
A                 1.00.01         yes
A                 1.01.00         no
B                 1.00.00         no
B                 1.00.01         yes
B                 1.00.02         no
```

I would like to have an SQL query (I use MS Access) that would return for each component the number of untested versions AFTER the last tested vesion.

So based on the previous exemple, I would like the output to be:

```
Component        Number Of Untested Version After Last Tested Vesion
--------------------------------------------------------------------
A                1
B                1
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers :)

Comment: Did you already tried something ? Or maybe you have an idea of how to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a query which could help you.
Please let me know if it meets your requirements.

```
DECLARE @ComponentVersionTable TABLE(
Id INT,
Component NVARCHAR(4),
Version NVARCHAR(16),
Tested BIT
)

INSERT INTO @ComponentVersionTable
VALUES(1, 'A', '1.00.00', 1),
  (2, 'A', '1.00.00', 1),
  (3, 'A', '1.00.01', 1),
  (4, 'A', '1.01.00', 0),
  (5, 'B', '1.00.00', 0),
  (6, 'B', '1.00.01', 1),
  (7, 'B', '1.00.02', 0)

SELECT 
    CVT.Component,
    Count(*)
FROM @ComponentVersionTable AS CVT
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                   Component,
                   MAX(Version) AS LatestTestedVersion
               FROM @ComponentVersionTable 
               WHERE Tested = 1
               GROUP BY Component) AS LTV ON LTV.Component = CVT.Component
WHERE CVT.Version > LTV.LatestTestedVersion
GROUP BY CVT.Component
```

Comment: Thx for your comment. It is an idea. So we can substitute WITH statement to a temporary table. Also, you can substitute BIT to boolean, NVARCHAR, etc. It is just an example.

Comment: I have changed the current query. I have moved with the body into subquery for result select statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly!!! And I think, I also learned when to use the JOIN statement :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
select Component,count(tested) from table
where tested='no'
group by Component
```

Comment: I didn't try, but this would return 2 untested versions for the component B. I would like only 1 untested version (since version 1.00.01 was tested).
I want to get only the untested versions after the last tested version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query in ms access :

```
SELECT t1.Component, count(*)
FROM yourtable as t1
    INNER JOIN (select component, max(version) as MaxVersion from yourtable 
          where tested='yes'
          group by component 
         ) as t2 
    ON t1.Component = t2.Component
WHERE t1.version > t2.MaxVersion 
GROUP BY t1.Component
```

This works in ms sql server ([DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e400b/2)) and i believe will work in ms access also.

Comment: It does work in ms access :) I accepted another answer, that was the exact same solution, just slightly more developped. Thanks again!

Comment: That's fine, though that answer is not a complete answer for ms access :)

Comment: It shouldn't work in Access - the `JOIN` statement should need an `INNER`, `LEFT` or `RIGHT`.  `MAX(Version)` can't be aliased as `Version` due to circular references, and I think aliasing in the `SELECT` part needs an `AS` (but not if aliasing in the `FROM` clause).

Comment: I'd suggest making these changes:  `SELECT T1.Component, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT Component, MAX(Version) AS MaxVersion FROM YourTable WHERE Tested = TRUE GROUP BY Component) T2 ON T1.Component = T2.Component WHERE T1.Version>T2.MaxVersion GROUP BY T1.Component`

Comment: Will `MAX(Version)` be a text comparison?  Will it muck up at any point on that?  Not sure (haven't checked or thought about it too much) - `MAX(CLNG(Replace([Version],".","")))` would change it to a real number.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Answer is updated according to your suggestion, yes it is text comparison and it works for similar patterned numeric values of string typed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
select sv.component, count(sv.version) as 
'Number Of Untested Version After Last Tested Version' 
from softwareVersion sv
where sv.tested = 'No'
and sv.version  > (select max(sv1.version)
                   from softwareVersion sv1
                   where sv1.tested = 'Yes'
                   and sv.component = sv1.component)
group by sv.component;
```